# Add table cell to existing table row, jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, html-table

I'm trying to add values to a table using jQuery - unfortunately, I don't know how to get jQuery to add table cells to an existing row. For example:

```
$("<td><a href='#'>" + key + "</a></td>").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    testset(key);
}).appendTo('#table1');
```

This adds cells to the end of the table with id `table1`. What would be the best way to go about adding cells to an existing table row (`<tr>`) using jQuery? Quick google hasn't revealed anything.
Regards,

SystemError

Comment: Change your `#table1` selector to refer to the table row in question. It would help if you explained more, such as which `tr` you would like to append to, along with a bit of your HTML.

Comment: Easiest way would be to give the `<tr>` and id. or use a selector such as `$('#table1 tr:last')`

Comment: Last known table row - thanks, $('#table1 tr:last') solved it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
.appendTo('#table1 #rowId');
```

Or you could do:

```
.appendTo('#table1 tr:nth-child(5)');
```

http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Answer (score 0):

You must append them to a specific row and not to the table:

```
$("<td><a href='#'>" + key + "</a></td>").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    testset(key);
}).appendTo('#table1 tr#yourrowId');
```