# Adding table cells to end of row using jquery based on radio button selections

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a (rather large) form which I am constructing. Within the form there are several radio button groups (Yes/No selections). After reading through several related posts here on StackOverflow I have been able to wright a jQuery function which will validate the radio buttons as they are clicked, however I have only been able to make it give a generic `alert()`. What I would like to happen when the "No" radio is selected is for the jQuery to add a new cell to the same table row with a message "This must be completed". The question posted by SystemError "[Add table cell to existing table row, jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7875176/add-table-cell-to-existing-table-row-jquery)" appears to give a good fix to my issue if I were to wright a jQuery function for each of the radio buttons. My question is, how would I accomplish this same goal using one function for all of the radio buttons? Here is my form as it stands right now with my attempt to add the cell, which adds the cell between the radio button and the label for it.

```js
// JavaScript Document
"use strict";
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);

function myTimer() {
  var d = new Date();
  var dd = d.getDay();
  var day1;
  var day2;
  var d_d = d.getMonth();
  switch (d_d) {
    case 0:
      day2 = "January";
      break;
    case 1:
      day2 = "February";
      break;
    case 2:
      day2 = "March";
      break;
    case 3:
      day2 = "April";
      break;
    case 4:
      day2 = "May";
      break;
    case 5:
      day2 = "June";
      break;
    case 6:
      day2 = "July";
      break;
    case 7:
      day2 = "August";
      break;
    case 8:
      day2 = "September";
      break;
    case 9:
      day2 = "October";
      break;
    case 10:
      day2 = "Novmber";
      break;
    case 11:
      day2 = "December";
      break;
  }
  switch (dd) {
    case 0:
      day1 = "Sunday";
      break;
    case 1:
      day1 = "Monday";
      break;
    case 2:
      day1 = "Tuesday";
      break;
    case 3:
      day1 = "Wednesday";
      break;
    case 4:
      day1 = "Thursday";
      break;
    case 5:
      day1 = "Friday";
      break;
    case 6:
      day1 = "Saterday";
      break;
  }
  document.getElementById("day").value = day1;
  document.getElementById("time").value = d.toLocaleTimeString();
  document.getElementById("date").value = day2 + " " + d.getDate();
}

function coldValidate(elem) {
  var x, text;
  x = +elem.value;
  if (isNaN(x) || x < 33 || x > 40) {
    text = "Temp Out of Tolerance";
  } else {
    text = " ";
  }
  elem.parentNode.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = text;
}

function freezValidate(elem) {
  var x, text;
  x = +elem.value;
  if (isNaN(x) || x < -10 || x > 10) {
    text = "Temp Out of Tolerance";
  } else {
    text = " ";
  }
  elem.parentNode.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = text;
}

function hotValidate(elem) {
  var x, text;
  x = +elem.value;
  if (isNaN(x) || x < 165) {
    text = "Temp Out of Tolerance";
  } else {
    text = " ";
  }
  elem.parentNode.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = text;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#storenumber").click(function salad() {
    var storenumber = $("#storenumber").val();
    switch (storenumber) {
      case "011169":
      case "008181":
        $("#frig1, #frig2, #frig3, #saladbar, #barcheese").removeClass("hide");
        break;
      case "010576":
      case "010324":
      case "008615":
      case "009150":
      case "014640":
      case "010684":
      case "011168":
      case "014215":
      case "008179":
      case "008339":
      case "008668":
      case "031574":
        $("#frig1, #frig2, #frig3, #saladbar, #barcheese").addClass("hide");
        break;
    }
  });
  $('input[type=radio]').on("change", function() {
    if ($(this).prop("value") === "False") {
      $(this).prepend("<td>This needs to be completed</td>");

    }
  });
});
```

```css
/* CSS Document */

header {
  text-align: center;
}
td {
  border: solid thin #000000;
  background-color: #FF0000;
}
th {
  border: solid thin #000000;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #FF0000;
}
.required {
  color: #FFF500;
}
.left {
  text-align: right;
  width: 480px;
}
.noborder {
  border: none;
  background-color: #061BFF;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
body {
  background-color: #061BFF;
}
.nobordererror {
  border: none;
  background-color: #061BFF;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <form>
    <section>
      <table cellspacing="0px">
        <tr>
          <th colspan="2" class="noborder">
            <h1>Food Safety Checklist</h1>
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="2" class="noborder"><span class="required">*</span>=Required feilds</th>
        </tr>
        <!-- Identification Information section -->
        <tr>
          <td class="left"><span class="required">*</span>Store Number:</td>
          <td>
            <select id="storenumber" name="storenumber" required title="Please select your store ID number">
              <option value="">Select Store Number</option>
              <option value="010576">010576</option>
              <option value="011169">011169</option>
              <option value="008181">008181</option>
              <option value="010324">010324</option>
              <option value="008615">008615</option>
              <option value="009150">009150</option>
              <option value="014640">014640</option>
              <option value="010684">010684</option>
              <option value="011168">011168</option>
              <option value="014215">014215</option>
              <option value="008179">008179</option>
              <option value="008339">008339</option>
              <option value="008668">008668</option>
              <option value="031574">031574</option>
            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="left"><span class="required">*</span>Day:</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="10" name="day" id="day" title="Enter current Day" required>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="left"><span class="required">*</span>Date:</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="9" name="date" id="date" required title="Please enter current date">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="left"><span class="required">*</span>Time:</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="6" name="time" id="time" title="Enter current time" required>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="left"><span class="required">*</span>Initials:</td>
          <td>
            <input name="initial" type="text" required id="initial" maxlength="2" size="3" title="Enter User ID">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" class="noborder">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <!-- Thermometer Calibration -->
        <tr>
          <th colspan="2" class="noborder">Thermometer</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="left"><span class="required">*</span>Thermometers Calibrated:</td>
          <td>
            <label>
              <input name="cal" type="radio" required id="cal_0" value="Yes" onChange="yesNo(this)">Yes</label>
            <label>
              <input name="cal" type="radio" required id="cal_1" value="No" onChange="yesNo(this)">No</label>
          </td>
          <td class="noborder"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" class="noborder">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <!-- Cold Temps -->
        <tr>
          <th colspan="2" class="noborder">Cold Temperature Managment</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="left"><span class="required">*</span>Maketable Air Temp (bottom):</td>
          <td>
            <input name="bottomair" type="text" required id="bottomair" size="3" onChange="coldValidate(this)">
          </td>
          <td class="noborder"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="left"><span class="required">*</span>Maketable Air Temp (top):</td>
          <td>
            <input name="topair" type="text" required id="topair" size="3" onChange="coldValidate(this)">
          </td>
          <td class="noborder"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="left"><span class="required">*</span>Maketable Meat Temp:</td>
          <td>
            <input name="meat" type="text" required id="meat" size="3" onChange="coldValidate(this)">
          </td>
          <td class="noborder"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="left"><span class="required">*</span>Maketable Cheese Temp:</td>
          <td>
            <input name="cheese" type="text" required id="cheese" size="3" onChange="coldValidate(this)">
          </td>
          <td class="noborder"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="left"><span class="required">*</span>Walk In Cooler Temp:</td>
          <td>
            <input name="walkin" type="text" required id="walkin" size="3" onChange="coldValidate(this)">
          </td>
          <td class="noborder"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="frig1" class="hide">
          <td class="left"><span class="required">*</span>Refrigeration Unit #1:</td>
          <td>
            <input name="refrig1" type="text" required id="refrig1" size="3" onChange="coldValidate(this)">
          </td>
          <td class="noborder"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="frig2" class="hide">
          <td class="left"><span class="required">*</span>Refrigeration Unit #2:</td>
          <td>
            <input name="refrig2" type="text" required id="refrig2" size="3" onChange="coldValidate(this)">
          </td>
          <td class="noborder"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="frig3" class="hide">
          <td class="left"><span class="required">*</span>Refrigeration Unit #3:</td>
          <td>
            <input name="refrig3" type="text" required id="refrig3" size="3" onChange="coldValidate(this)">
          </td>
          <td class="noborder"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="left"><span class="required">*</span>Freezer Unit #1:</td>
          <td>
            <input name="freez1" type="text" required id="freez1" size="3" onChange="freezValidate(this)">
          </td>
          <td class="noborder"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="left"><span class="required">*</span>Freezer Unit #2:</td>
          <td>
            <input name="freez2" type="text" required id="freez2" size="3" onChange="freezValidate(this)">
          </td>
          <td class="noborder"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="left"><span class="required">*</span>Freezer Unit #3:</td>
          <td>
            <input name="freez3" type="text" required id="freez3" size="3" onChange="freezValidate(this)">
          </td>
          <td class="noborder"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="saladbar" class="hide">
          <td class="left"><span class="required">*</span>Salad Bar Air Temp:</td>
          <td>
            <input name="saladair" type="text" required id="saladair" size="3" onChange="coldValidate(this)">
          </td>
          <td class="noborder"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="barcheese" class="hide">
          <td class="left"><span class="required">*</span>Salad Bar Cheese Temp:</td>
          <td>
            <input name="saladcheese" type="text" required id="saladcheese" size="3" onChange="coldValidate(this)">
          </td>
          <td class="noborder"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="noborder" colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <!-- Hot Temp section -->
        <tr>
          <th class="noborder" colspan="2">Hot Temperature Management</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="left"><span class="required">*</span>Wing Temp:</td>
          <td>
            <input name="wing" type="text" required id="wing" size="3" onChange="hotValidate(this)">
          </td>
          <td class="noborder"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="left"><span class="required">*</span>Meat Sauce/Soups Temp:</td>
          <td>
            <input name="sauce" type="text" required id="sauce" size="3" onChange="hotValidate(this)">
          </td>
          <td class="noborder"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="left"><span class="required">*</span>Hot Hold Timing System:</td>
          <td>
            <label>
              <input name="hothold" type="radio" required id="hothold_0" value="Yes">Yes</label>
            <label>
              <input name="hothold" type="radio" required id="hothold_1" value="No">No</label>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="noborder" colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <!-- Oven Managment -->
        <tr>
          <th class="noborder" colspan="2">Oven Management</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="left"><span class="required">*</span>Pizza Tepmp:</td>
          <td>
            <input name="pizza" type="text" required id="pizza" size="3" onChange="hotValidate(this)">
          </td>
          <td class="noborder"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="left"><span class="required">*</span>Pasta Temp:</td>
          <td>
            <input name="pasta" type="text" required id="pasta" size="3" onChange="hotValidate(this)">
          </td>
          <td class="noborder"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="noborder" colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <!-- Oven speed and temp only needsto be done once a week -->
        <tr>
          <th class="noborder" colspan="2">Oven Temperatures and Speeds</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="left">Top Oven:</td>
          <td>
            Temp:
            <input name="toptemp" type="text" id="toptemp" maxlength="3" size="4">
            <br/>Speed:
            <input name="topspeed" type="text" id="topspeed" maxlength="3" size="4">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="left">Center Oven:</td>
          <td>
            Temp:
            <input name="centertemp" type="text" id="centertemp" maxlength="3" size="4">
            <br/>Speed:
            <input name="centerspeed" type="text" id="centerspeed" maxlength="3" size="4">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="left">Bottom Oven:</td>
          <td>
            Temp:
            <input name="bottomtemp" type="text" id="bottomtemp" maxlength="3" size="4">
            <br/>Speed:
            <input name="bottomspeed" type="text" id="bottomspeed" maxlength="3" size="4">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="noborder" colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <!-- This is the Yes/No section of the checklist
            Food Handling Section -->
        <tr>
          <th class="noborder" colspan="2">Food Hangling</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="left"><span class="required">*</span>Only approved Ingredients Used:</td>
          <td>
            <label>
              <input name="approve" type="radio" required value="True">Yes</label>
            <label>
              <input name="approve" type="radio" required value="False">No</label>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="left"><span class="required">*</span>No Spoiled/Expired food present:</td>
          <td>
            <label>
              <input name="expired" type="radio" required value="True">Yes</label>
            <label>
              <input name="expired" type="radio" required value="False">No</label>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="left"><span class="required">*</span>Wing Street Raw Zone Process Followed:</td>
          <td>
            <label>
              <input name="raw" type="radio" required value="True">Yes</label>
            <label>
              <input name="raw" type="radio" required value="False">No</label>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="left"><span class="required">*</span>Foodis Correcctly Date/Labeled &amp; FIFO is followed:</td>
          <td>
            <label>
              <input name="fifo" type="radio" required value="True">Yes</label>
            <label>
              <input name="fifo" type="radio" required value="False">No</label>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="left"><span class="required">*</span>Whole Produce is Washed:</td>
          <td>
            <label>
              <input name="produce" type="radio" required value="True">Yes</label>
            <label>
              <input name="produce" type="radio" required value="False">No</label>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- Sanitation Section -->
        <tr>
          <td class="left"><span class="required">*</span>Sanitizer is at Correct PPM:</td>
          <td>
            <label>
              <input name="ppm" type="radio" required value="True">Yes</label>
            <label>
              <input name="ppm" type="radio" required value="False">No</label>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="left"><span class="required">*</span>Hot Water &ge; 120&deg;F at 3-Comp. Sink:</td>
          <td>
            <label>
              <input name="hotwater" type="radio" required value="True">Yes</label>
            <label>
              <input name="hotwater" type="radio" required value="False">No</label>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="left"><span class="required">*</span>Dishwasher has Soap &amp; Sanitizer or &ge; 180&deg;F Water:</td>
          <td>
            <label>
              <input name="soap" type="radio" required value="True">Yes</label>
            <label>
              <input name="soap" type="radio" required value="False">No</label>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="left"><span class="required">*</span>Chemicals stored Correctly:</td>
          <td>
            <label>
              <input name="chem" type="radio" required value="True">Yes</label>
            <label>
              <input name="chem" type="radio" required value="False">No</label>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- Health & Hygiene Section -->
        <tr>
          <th class="left"><span class="required">*</span>No Ill Team Members Working:</th>
          <td>
            <label>
              <input name="illteam" type="radio" required value="True">Yes</label>
            <label>
              <input name="illteam" type="radio" required value="False">No</label>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="left"><span class="required">*</span>Correct Hand Washing Procedures Followed:</td>
          <td>
            <label>
              <input name="wash" type="radio" required value="True">Yes</label>
            <label>
              <input name="wash" type="radio" required value="False">No</label>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="left"><span class="required">*</span>Hand Sinks (Including Restrooms) are Stocked, Accessible &amp; Used Properly:</td>
          <td>
            <label>
              <input name="sinks" type="radio" required value="True">Yes</label>
            <label>
              <input name="sinks" type="radio" required value="False">No</label>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="left"><span class="required">*</span>Hair Restraints Worn Correctly:</td>
          <td>
            <label>
              <input name="hair" type="radio" required value="True">Yes</label>
            <label>
              <input name="hair" type="radio" required value="False">No</label>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- Pest Management Section -->
        <tr>
          <td class="left"><span class="required">*</span>Pest Infestation or Activity is not Present and All Traps Placed Correctly:</td>
          <td>
            <label>
              <input name="pest" type="radio" required value="True">Yes</label>
            <label>
              <input name="pest" type="radio" required value="False">No</label>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </section>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>

</body>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do a couple of things for that like below. Check demo - [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/gq6j2bop/)

1. remove `onChange="yesNo(this)"` handler from you html markup, because you are attaching a general handler.
2. Change `if ($(this).prop("value") === "False") {` to `if ($(this).prop("value") === "No") {` because there is no `False` values in you radios.
3. Prepend a new `td` not to the input checkbox like you do, but to the `td` that holds that checkbox: `$(this).closest('td').prepend("<td>This needs to be completed</td>");`

So your general handler would look like:

```
$('input[type=radio]').on("change", function() {
    if ($(this).prop("value") === "No") {
        $(this).closest('td').prepend("<td>This needs to be completed</td>");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, however after looking at my coding, I realized that I already had a blank cell set up for this information. how would I go about adding the statement to this cell. I have tried using `.next().prepend()` but this is not working

Comment: If you already has an empty `td` which is following the one with radio you would do `$(this).closest('td').next().html("This needs to be completed</td>");`. If the empty `td` goes before the one with radio you would do `$(this).closest('td').prev().html("This needs to be completed</td>");`

Comment: Thank you, this appears to be working in the jsFidle file. Now all I have to do is transfer it to my live page.

Comment: Only remove the ending `</td>` from my previous comment - a typo.